# Keep cursor on textarea after clicking on DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea in which text pieces (stored on each `data-code` attribute) are appended when clicking on an specific DIV:

```
$(document).on('click', '.extrasPanel .contentVars div', function(e){
        varCode = $('.active').attr('data-code');
        varText=$(document).find('textarea').val();
        $(document).find('textarea').val(varText+varCode);
        checkCounter(e);
});
```

Once a `.contenVars div` is clicked, its `data-code` value is added to whatever is typed on textarea, and to keep typing the user must click again on the textarea.

I would like the user to keep typing after importing this pieces of text widthout needing to click back on it, so that the cursor remains on the last position, after the last imported character (as if you would have pasted it).

I have tried adding `e.preventDefault;` at the end of the function, with no possitive result.

Comment: Try $('textarea_selector').focus();

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can try [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

```
jQuery('textarea').focus();
```

Comment: This will take the cursor to beginning of the textarea input.

Comment: this is also possible with just javascript: `document.getElementById("textarea").focus();`

Comment: @Biomehanika Check out my answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

May this link will helps you..

[jquery-caret.js](https://github.com/DrPheltRight/jquery-caret)

This is a very simple lightweight plugin to allow you to move the caret (or cursor) position in an  or  element

```
$('textarea').caretToEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you. If possible, I'd like to avoid plugins use, but may be useful for other users. Very grateful.